# Hardening Drupal server running the Update Manager

Tags: updating, security

We are going to do the hardening on one of our Linux server running SELinux and  Drupal 7 with firewall; on the Drupal Update Manager, if we want only to get periodic emails / notifications on modules / cores update but NOT update using the UI via SSH / FTP, what ports should we enable on the server and what URL (on the formal Drupal website??) need to be unblocked? What SELinux setting need to be set?

Also, what ports to be enable and setting need to be done for using Drush for update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question:
After investigating the update module of Drupal 7.4, I found that Drupal will try to fetch the update information *usually* from

```
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/<project_name>/<drupal_api_compatibility_version>
```

using drupal_http_request function, where project name is usually the plugin module name
e.g.

```
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x
```

that means the server need to allow the port 80 for the operation to access pages

```
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/*/*
```

However, if the plugin module have its own update URL, the update check will check this instead of drupal update site.
Therefore, SELinux must allow for network operation, use this command to turn it on:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question regarding ports.

But I will recommend installing the [Update Status Advanced Settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/update_advanced) module to tailor the notification messages you get from Drupal:

> Users of the 5.x Update status contrib module will probably want to
>   use this once they upgrade to 6.x, since some of the functionality in
>   the contrib version was deemed too complicated to include in core. In
>   particular, the per-project settings to ignore certain projects or
>   even specific releases, is absent in the core version of the module.
>   The "Update status advanced settings" module restores these settings,
>   and might eventually provide additional functionality for the core
>   "Update status" module.

This way if your site uses Features, or custom made modules not hosted on Drupal.org the update notification will not inform you of issues related to looking up version information on them. But you'll have to configure this setting on a site by site basis -- it's not a system-wide server configuration.